# defined regex in outer scope make different result in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I make an example here:

```js
var reg = /\s+/g;

function testfn() {

  // reg = /\s+/g;

  var res = reg.test('mike ross');

  var showEle = document.querySelector("#show");
  showEle.innerHTML = res;

}
```

```html
<button onclick="testfn()">click</button>
<span id="show"></span>
```

as you can click the button, and will find there's different result when
you click again and again.

but defined the regex in function inside (comment the line inside),then
you found it work as before.

why???

Comment: We stop you using jsfiddle directly because we want the question to be self-contained. The code should be posted here.

Comment: oh~,i see, will do it next time,thanks for copy the code!!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0 for how to create a Stack Snippet, which is like jsfiddle but built into SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expression objects using the `g` flag *have state*, so that you can loop through all matches in a string. When you use the same object again, it continues from where it left off. When you create a new one each time (by creating it in the function), it starts at the beginning each time.

The state is in the `lastIndex` property, which (despite the name) says where to begin matching next time. Here's your example reusing the same global object, and showing `lastIndex` after each operation:

```js
var reg = /\s+/g;

function testfn() {

  var str = "Matching starting at " + reg.lastIndex;

  var res = reg.test('mike ross');

  var showEle = document.querySelector("#show");
  showEle.innerHTML = str += ", res = " + res;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="testfn()">click</button>
<span id="show"></span>
```

Vs. creating a new object every time:

```js
function testfn() {

  var reg = /\s+/g;
  var str = "Matching starting at " + reg.lastIndex;

  var res = reg.test('mike ross');

  var showEle = document.querySelector("#show");
  showEle.innerHTML = str += ", res = " + res;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="testfn()">click</button>
<span id="show"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `g` modifier. This modifier makes the regexp remember the place where it last matched, and every time you use it it looks for the next match after that.

With the global variable, there's just one `RegExp` object, and it remembers its position across all the calls to the function.

With a local variable, the `RegExp` object gets recreated every time you call the function, so it starts looking from the beginning of the string.